# android studio: java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()

Tags: android, android-studio, knx

i'm trying to make an app by using calimero library for KNX. In my app, i use some buttons, switches, togglebuttons, etc to switch on/off the lights.
With 'Button', everything works well. I can switch on/off a light or open/close curtains.

```
private class button9OnClickListener implements View.OnClickListener {
    public void onClick(View view){

        try {
            falseTask dt = new falseTask();
            String adr = "5/1/0";
            dt.execute(adr);

        } catch (Exception e) {

        }

    }

}
```

But when i use 'Switch' with either OnClickListener or OnCheckedChangeListenser, it crash.

```
private class switch1OnCheckedChangeListener implements CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener {
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean isChecked) {
        if(compoundButton.isChecked()) {

            try {
                trueTask dt = new trueTask();
                String adr = "5/4/6";
                dt.execute(adr);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


        } else {

            try {
                falseTask dt = new falseTask();
                String adr = "5/4/6";
                dt.execute(adr);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

}
```

the problem is below:

```
uncaughtException   java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
```

and here's my doInBackground

```
        protected String doInBackground(String...strings){

        String adr = strings[0];

        try {

            final InetSocketAddress localEP = new InetSocketAddress(InetAddress.getByName(hostip), 0);
            final InetSocketAddress remoteEP = new InetSocketAddress(remoteip, knxServerPort);

            knxLink = new KNXNetworkLinkIP(KNXNetworkLinkIP.TUNNEL, localEP, remoteEP, true, TPSettings.TP1);

            pc = new ProcessCommunicatorImpl(knxLink);
            pc.write(new GroupAddress(adr), true);
            knxLink.close();

        }
        catch (final KNXException e) {

        }
        catch (final UnknownHostException e) {

        }

        return null;
    }
```

i'm new to java and android programming. Can you help with this problem? i can't understand why this work for 'button' but not for 'switch'.

Thank you in advance

**UPDATE**

I copy my code and try with eclipse. Everything work fine. I can switch on/off the light i want and there is no error.
With android studio, it did not work. Someone know the reason?

Comment: can you post the stacktrace

Comment: @pArAs uncaughtException   java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground() that' all for what i got with stacktrace

Comment: Add a generic catch block and print the exceptions.. catch (final Exception e) { StackTraceElement trace[] = e.getStackTrace();
            for (StackTraceElement aTrace : trace) {
                Log.e(LOG_TAG, aTrace.toString());
            } }

Comment: @GuilhermeP I added what you told me and i got nothing at all

Answer (score 1):

I tried with ToggleButton and Switch in Eclipse. All work good. I put exactly what I used in android studio. I copy all the code without any change. Can't understand the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Finally I find the problem. I use 2 Bundle in the MainActivity and I use these 2 Bundle in doInBackground for my AsyncTask in the SecondActivity. But I just pass on the first Bundle to the SecondActivity and I forget to pass on the second Bundle. So I got error while executing doInBackground() What foolish mistake I have made...